# Postagens automáticas no facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Tenho um sistema onde utilizo o `cURL` para fazer login em um site. Nesse site eu tenho um botão de compartilhar conteúdo do facebook, quero fazer isso automaticamente. Ou seja, acabar com o trabalho de o usuário entrar no site, e compartilhar o conteúdo. Qual forma posso fazer isso? Usando a `API` do facebook? Alguém pode me dar algum rumo?

EDIT: Acho que não fui bem claro na minha pergunta, não quero criar o botão de compartilhar, ele já está criado, eu só quero conseguir clica-lo com o cURL, e compartilhar o conteúdo, só que pra isso o usuário teria que estar logado certo? Minha dificuldade esta ai.

Comment: Defina melhor como é seu sistema e o que gostaria de fazer?
A parte de "clicar com o cURL" não esta muito clara.
Este outro site que possui o botão de compartilhar é seu ou de outra pessoa?

Comment: Vou tentar descrever melhor, o site é de outra pessoa, todo dia eu tenho que entrar nesse site, fazer login e senha nele, e então clicar em um botão de compartilhar que tem lá, e compartilhar o conteúdo dentro de um grupo que tenho no facebook. O que eu queria que o sistema fizesse era fazer isso todo automático, com o cURL, sem eu precisar ter que fazer login, clicar, compartilhar entende? Eu só executasse o script e ele fizesse tudo.

Comment: Precisa necessariamente utilizar cURL? Isso parece mais uma tarefa de automatização sua. Se puder utilizar outras ferramentas você pode tentar utilizar o AutoIT ou o AutoHotKey que server para automatizar estas tarefas suas no desktop.
Ou ainda o Selenium, que vai automatizar esta tarefa pra você de clicar no botão de compartilhar. Existe até um bind para o selenium usando PHP aqui -> http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Nao precisa ser necessariamente com o cURL, mas eu quero fazer um sistema que nao seja restrito a mim, depois que eu conseguir fazer para mim, quero conseguir fazer para varias pessoas, armazenando os dados delas (com concentimento claro). No fim de tudo quero que quando eu executar o script, um por um o sistema entre, compartilha, saia, entre, compartilha e saia. Mas vou dar uma lida nesse selenium, valeu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de qualquer coisa você precisa criar uma chave para seu aplicativo [Aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/).

Depois ir até a Aba Apps, Create New App

[image: Aba Apps]

Depois do aplicativo criado você pode pegar o `APP ID` aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois disso, você pode utilizar o botão de share em cada um dos conteúdos assim.

No `HTML`:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10272/postagens-automaticas-no-facebook" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

No `Javascript`:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

No lugar de XXXXXXXXXXXXXX você deve colocar a chave do seu aplicativo.

Você pode utilizar o `cURL` como indicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814158/post-to-a-facebook-users-wall-with-curl-php)
Mas acredito que é muito mais simples utilizar o `PHP` para esta tarefa, até porque você vai precisar do acess_token de acesso, conseguido só depois de fazer um login com seu 
aplicativo na `API` do `Facebook`.

Para automatizar usando `PHP` você deve utilizar a API do `Facebook`, usando o `SDK` em `PHP`.
[Aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) tem o link para a documentação do `SDK`
E [aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/) tem um exemplo de como postar usando `PHP` e a `API` do `Facebook`

Os passos para a criação do `APP ID` são os mesmos

Comment: Se possível olha o que editei na minha pergunta, sua resposta ta ótima mas não é o que eu preciso.

Comment: @Leonardo Otto e para eu postar em uma outra timeline ? exemplo: pedir autorização para um usuário e postar automaticamente na timeline dele ?